# How can I construct a Golden Ratio Gauge like this? What shall be the legs of such a gauge?

Tags: geometry, golden-ratio

How can I construct such Golden Ratio Gauge?

What shall be the lengths of respective legs (their parts)?

$M, P, N$ - are *sharpened tips (endpoints)*

$A, B, C, D$ - *joints (screw-points)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{AC}$, $\overline{BD}$, $\overline{CD}$ are all one unit long, then $\overline{BM}$, $\overline{BP}$, $\overline{CN}$ need to be $\phi$ units long.

You can see this by drawing a line through $P$ parallel to $\overline{CD}$.  Let's say this line intersects $\overline{AN}$ at $Z$.  Then the parallelogram $AZPB$ is the usual golden rectangle, skewed into a parallelogram.  Triangles $\triangle MBP$ and $\triangle PZN$ are similar with side-length ratios $\phi$.